# Proof that $((P∧Q)→(P∨Q))\to (P→Q)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I can't seem to get from $(P \wedge Q) \to (P \vee Q)$ to $(P\to Q).$

Based on what I understand, we use the logical conditional statement
$$P \to Q \equiv\; \sim P \vee Q$$ to get $\sim (P \vee Q) \vee (P \vee Q).$ Then we use De Morgan's Law to get $(\sim P$ $\vee \sim Q) \vee (P \vee Q)$. After using the associative and communicative laws, we end up with $(\sim P$ $\vee \sim Q) \vee (P \vee Q),$ which is logically equivalent to $(P \to Q)$ because $P \to Q \equiv\;\sim P \vee Q.$

Comment: List of inference rules , Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to get from $$(P \wedge Q) \to (P \vee Q)$$ to $$(P\to Q).$$

As pointed out by Alessandro, the former is a tautology. The latter is not a tautology. Since it is impossible for a non-tautology (the latter) to be a tautological consequence of a tautology (the former), the required proof is impossible to produce.

> $\lnot(P \vee Q) \vee (P \vee Q)$.
>
> Then we use De Morgan's Law to get $(\lnot P \vee \lnot Q) \vee (P \vee Q).$

A mistake: the second line ought to be $$(\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \vee (P \vee Q).$$

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong, because $P\wedge Q\rightarrow P\vee Q$ is always true. You can see this by doing the calculations as you've done them, thus getting $$(\sim P\vee\sim Q)\vee(P\vee Q)=(\sim P\vee P)\vee(\sim Q\vee Q)=\text{true}\vee\text{true}=\text{true}$$
or, just by looking at the meaning of the implication, which is "If $P$ and $Q$ are true, then $P$ or $Q$ are true", which is clearly true. In particular, it is true even if $P\rightarrow Q$ is false, which means that they cannot be equivalent.

Comment: But wouldn't this part (∼P∨∼Q)∨(P∨Q) be equal to ~P v Q which is the same as P-> Q?

Comment: Can you write down all the passages to get from $(\sim P\vee\sim Q)\vee(P\vee Q)$ to $\sim P\vee Q$?

Comment: No, I just started doing exercises for these so I’m not actually good at it but we were given a logical equivalence formula which shows  P -> Q = ~P v Q and i assumed that (~P v Q) is ~P and (P v Q) is Q in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, but you either show that $\sim P\vee Q$ can be derived from $(\sim P\vee \sim Q)\vee(P\vee Q)$ by the logical laws (Morgan's law, associativity, etc), or prove that one can be true while the other is false. In this case, the second expression is always true, while the first can be false (for example $P$ true and $Q$ false), so they cannot be equivalent, because logical laws preserve the truth (so if the second is always true, then the first must also be always true)